# Permission already granted but keep telling not granted REACT-NATIVE

Tags: react-native, android-studio

im building a music player and I need to acces to the music files, so the first thing is ask for permissions to acces to the files:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.requestPermission();
}

requestPermission = async () => {
 
    try {

        const userResponse = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      
        ]);

        if (userResponse === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            alert("nice");
        }else {
            alert("no nice");
        }
        
    }catch (error) {
        alert(error)
    }
};
```

even when I already clicked in allow, and reload the project it wil say no nice, i open the config of the app and the permission to storage is fine, so dont why is this happening

Comment: I am not sure but as far  as I know you have also to add the Permission to your Manifest

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [requestMultiple](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid) will return an object with the permissions as keys and strings as values (see result strings above) indicating whether the user allowed or denied the request or does not want to be asked again.

**try this**

```
if (userResponse[PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED && userResponse[PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] ===
 PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED
 ) {
  alert('nice');
 } else {
  alert('no nice');
}
```